# Swift functions with parameters unable to expose to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I found that all my Swift class functions with parameters cannot be exposed to Objective-C.

```
class func debug(var message : String) {
   Log.debug?.message(message)
}

func addTask(var newTask : UploadXfdfCommand) {
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, { () -> Void in
        tasks?.append(newTask)
    })
}
```

I have already set the annotation @objc to my swift class and related objects. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made some silly mistake...just remove the var in the parameter and the function is enable to expose to objective-c